# File size changes while sending an image from android device to server

Tags: android, image-processing

Following is the android code to compress before sending..

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
        String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(baos.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);
```

At the server side , the code to receive the image is

```
<?php
    $image = $_POST["image"];
    $name = $_POST["name"];

    $decodedImage = base64_decode("$image");
    file_put_contents("image/" . $name . ".PNG",$decodedImage);
?>
```

At the client side, the file size is 178 KB and after receiving at the server the file size is 146 KB. PNG is the format followed to avoid the loss of data, but still the data is lost. How to get the same file in this case??

Comment: I see no file at client side. And if you want the same file you should upload the file. Not mess around with bitmaps.

Comment: Agreed. Compare the length of your byte array (before base64 encoding) to the size of the file on the server.

Comment: bmp is a Bitmap image at the client side.

Comment: Upload the file ?  But we must convert it to string before sending right?? That's why Base64 is used here..

Comment: There still is no file visible.

Comment: Didn't get you... I have read an image in the bmp variable which is of type 'Bitmap' ....bmp represents a huge bunch of data..